# Can Outlook Forms be viewable by other not using Outlook as their email program?

Tags: outlook-form

I have created a custom Outlook form in 2007 and I have some receipeints that need to visualize it but do not use Outlook as their email program.  Is it possible to make changes to the Form to ensure that they are able to view the form as an email?

Comment: Other users most likely will only see the (HTML-) body of the item. But best you simply try out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.